# .gz (gzip) file analysis

Tags: gzip, rfc

According to RFC 1952 ("GZIP File Format Specification"), a gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data sets).

Is it possible to analyze a gzip file without decompressing it, for example count up the number of members and index their locations within the file, or go into the middle of the file and find and decompress just one of the members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To find when a member ends, you have to decompress it. You don't have to write out the decompressed result — just process the input to find where the members start.

Once you know where the members start, then yes, you can start decompression from any one of those locations.

Note that the vast majority of gzip files have just one member.